# Wordpress: In all products list (Woocommerce) - how to show product description

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WordPress Woocommerce webstore with ~ 30K products and not all of them have a description. I need a way to see product description from product listing in WordPress admin panel (doesn't even have to be full description, an except would be sufficient), or at least a way to somehow filter out products that don't have description. I have thoroughly searched for a solution here and on the rest of the web but I can't seem to find an answer. Please help and thanks in advance!

Comment: Any ideas, anyone, please?

Answer (score 2):

You may try this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/

it is actually adding new columns to the WP admin panel, and it is said in the description that it integrates with the woocommerce also.

As the other idea, check this tutorial: https://upstatement.com/blog/2014/02/adding-columns-to-the-wordpress-admin-the-easy-way/
I've used that approach to show new columns with content from advanced custom fields plugin, so I guess there should be a way to display WooCommerce info
.

Comment: @johnnybravo , you are welcome! I'll appreciate then if you can vote my answer, thanks

Comment: The plugin works easily. Free version has the functionality to display the "Excerpt" and also "Content" which shows the woocommerce "Product short description" and "Product description" respectively.